# Tooltipster not working properly

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, plugins, tooltipster

I'm trying to code a chrome extension which highlights certain names and gives you additional information about the name inside a tooltip. Basically, I have an object with names and IDs like this:

```
var list = {
    'Name1' : 'ID0001',
    'Name2' : 'ID0002',
}
```

Then I'm using a jQuery highlight plugin to highlight every occurance of the keys in the document and assigning a span element with a class corresponding to the value of the key (for Example ID0001), which works fine...

```
$.each(list, function(key, value) {
    $("p").highlight(key, {caseSensitive: false, className: value });
});
```

and results in this:

```
<span class="ID0001">Name_1</span>
```

Next, I'm trying to select every element with a class name containing the first part of the ID and activate Tooltipster:

```
$('span[class*=ID]').tooltipster({
    interactive: true,
    content: $(<p>Loading...</p>),
    contentAsHTML: true,
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        continueTooltip();

        // Below, I'm trying to get whole ID, without the 
        // 'tooltipstered' class, that Tooltipster assigned.
        var id = $(this).attr('class').replace(' tooltipstered','');

        $.getJSON(chrome.extension.getURL('db.json'), function(db) {
        // Inside here, I'm using the ID to get information from a json 
        // file and store it in a variable called 'content', e.g.
        var content = '<p>db[id].link</p>';

        // Then I'm trying to update the content of the tooltip:
            origin.tooltipster({
                content: content,
                contentAsHTML: true
        });
   }
});
```

All of this code is inside this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  });
```

Now, if I hover over a span with a name inside for the first time, tooltipster won't do anything, and the Chrome console will say this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined
```

But I hover over it a second time it will show me the correct content. Additionally, If I hover over a name for the first time and another name the second time, the tooltip will show the content for the first name.

I'm fairly new to JS and jQuery and I just can't find out what I'm doing wrong here.

I've found a few other threads about similar issues, bt none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

Here is the "complete" updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.each(list, function(key, value) {
    $("p").highlight(key, {caseSensitive: false, className: value });
});

$('span[class*=ID]').tooltipster({
    interactive: true,
    contentAsHTML: true,
    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        continueTooltip();
        var id = $(this).attr('class').replace(' tooltipstered','');
        var content = generate_content(id);
        origin.tooltipster('content', content);
    }

});

function generate_content(id) {
    $.getJSON(chrome.extension.getURL('db.json'), function(db) {
        // Getting information from the .sjon and storing it in "content"
    });
    return content;
}

});
```

Comment: From what I can see there's a few missing curly brackets from your code, could you resolve this? One thing to remember is that `$.getJSON` is not asynchronous and will be the reason the content isn't showing until the request for the JSON content has completed :)

Comment: How could I wait for $.getJSON to finish before continuing?

Comment: I don't generally use `$.getJSON` but have you tried retro-fitting your example to follow the `functionBefore` example on the site http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#functionBeforeExample? It would need modifying to use `GET` and the data type should be `JSON` :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the call to $.getJSON is asynchronous, you should update the content of the tooltipster in the done callback of the $.getJSON. You can use something like the code below -

```
$('span[class*=ID]').tooltipster({
    interactive: true,
    contentAsHTML: true,
    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        continueTooltip();
        var id = $(this).attr('class').replace(' tooltipstered','');
        generate_content(id, origin);
    }
});

function generate_content(id, origin) {
    $.getJSON(chrome.extension.getURL('db.json'), function(db) {
        // Getting information from the .sjon and storing it in "content"
         var content -  set the content here.
         origin.tooltipster('content', content);

    });
}
```

})